# QuickBlox Messages UDIDs

Tags: ios, quickblox, udid

I'm using QuickBlox for Apple Push Notification Services, while debugging some problems I had a look at their QuickBlox panel:Messages->Devices and I notice there are multiple devices for some users with different UDIDs. These users have only used one device and none of the device UDIDs seem to tie in with the actual iPhone UDIDs as seen on iTunes.

Does anyone know where these UDIDs come from, what they signify and why there are more than one per user?

Comment: Those should not be UDID's but push tokens, a push token is unique for the app installed on that device. If you change profiles (ad-hoc, development or appstore) the push token may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps are not allowed to access the device UDID.

The API for accessing a unique identifier for each device will return a new random ID if you uninstall then reinstall the app.

This is specifically designed to make it impossible for an app to track users of the app.

You must ask the user to type in their email or something, if you want to tell one user from another.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The app is not accessing the device UDID, I was just looking at them in the panel. So the 'UDID' that I can see in the panel is just a random number - nothing to do with the device's actual UDID. There have been problems with QuickBlox in this area in the past and I just wanted to ensure this wasn't causing my problems. Thanks for the info

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood your answer - presumably you are referring to Apple's API that QuickBlox uses?

Comment: Yeah. I don't know how QuickBlox works, but it used to be possible to access the UDID and this was commonly done. Apple realised it was being used maliciously by some app developers (especially with regard to COPPA compliance and the like), and replaced it with an "identifier for vendor" that works the way I described and matches what you're seeing. I'm 99% sure QuicBlox is using that, they just didn't change the name on their end.